# Intuition for the definition of smooth manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, intuition

**The Definition**

Let $M,U \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ and $a \in M$.

a) $M$ is $r$-smooth in $a$ $:\Leftrightarrow$ $\exists C^r$- Submersion $g \in C^r(U,\mathbb{R^{n-m}})$ in $a$ with $U\cap M = g^{-1}(\{0\}).$

b)$M$ is $C^r$-Manifold in $\mathbb{R^n}$ $:\Leftrightarrow$ $\forall x \in M: M$ is $r$-smooth in $x$.

My lecture notes also state that $M$ is a set of zeroes of $n-m$ independent equations.

**My thoughts**

I understand the first part of a), that we want to call something smooth in a point if there is a function that is $C^r$ at that point. Other than that I'm quite lost to be honest.

I have seen an other definition (through an Atlas), that make more sense to me so the general idea of a manifold is clearer, however I can't square it with the definition above.

**The Questions**

- Intuitively: Why does it have to be a Submersion? (Instead of an Immersion or a local Diffeomorphism for example)
- Why the condition $U\cap M = g^{-1}(\{0\})$ and what is the connection to $g$ being a Submersion?
- What are the $n-m$ independent equations and why are there $n-m$?

Edit: Thanks to @TedShifrin to pointing out that the equations have to be independent instead of dependent.

Comment: Have you seen the Implicit Function Theorem?

Comment: Which textbook is it?

Comment: This is the definition of an $m$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that generalizes the definition of a hypersurface as the level set of a smooth function. Note that $n-m$ is the codimension, so you need $n-m$ equations to specify the submanifold instead of only one in the case of a hypersurface.

Comment: The assumption that the map is a submersion is the higher codimension analogue of the function having nonzero differential in the hypersurface case.

Comment: Check your statement above "My thoughts" and again at the end. It should be $n-m$ *independent* equations. You're defining an $m$-dimensional submanifold of $\Bbb R^n$ by cutting it out by *independent* equations. Each equation lowers the dimension by $1$, and so you need $n-m$ to get to dimension $m$. [Think through the linear case. This is the model.]

Comment: @Thorgott I have seen it and I can see that there has to be some connection but it's not clear to me.

Comment: @PaulFrost Sorry, I meant to write lecture notes.

Comment: @Deane Thanks, that helped!

Comment: In its present form the defnition has some defects. (1)  What does "$C^r$- submersion $g \in C^r(U,\mathbb{R^{n-m}})$ in $a$" mean? I guess it means $a \in U$. (2) It seems that you want to define **$m$-dimensional** $C^r$-manifolds in $\mathbb R^n$. But nothing is mentioned concerming the role of $m$  in $g \in C^r(U,\mathbb{R^{n-m}})$. Theoretically it could mean that there exists some such $m$. Then you have to show that $m$ is uniquely determined by $a$ (which can be done) and that you get the the same $m$ at all points of $M$ (which is in general not true).